# variable declaration is considered as a command in bash

Tags: bash, declare

Why is `int"$((++k))"=test` considered as a command by bash? Example:

```
$ int1=test
$ int"$((++k))"=test
bash: int1=test: command not found
$
```

I know that I could use `declare int"$((++k))"=test`, but why doesn't `int"$((++k))"=test` work?

Comment: This is solvable using `eval`. Note that what's sent to `eval` will be processed once by the shell.

Comment: You're trying to *generate* variables.  In [tag:bash] this requires `eval` when assigning values, or indirection `${!var}` on evaluation.  In [tag:ksh]93, `nameref` (alias for `typeset -n`) can do both.

Comment: `bash` 4.3 (to be released) will also support name refs with `declare -n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is specified in [POSIX 2.10.2.7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02) on the Shell Command Language (emphasis mine):

> If **all the characters preceding '=' form a valid name** (see the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 3.230, Name), the token ASSIGNMENT_WORD shall be returned. (**Quoted characters cannot participate in forming a valid name.**)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` like below to solve your problem with variable generation:

```
eval int$((++k))=test
```

Note that what's sent to `eval` will be processed once by the shell.

Answer (score -1):

Because the bash [grammar](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/unix/1565923472/syntax/lbs.appd.div.3) requires so.

```
<letter> ::= a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|
             A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z

<digit> ::= 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9

<number> ::= <digit>
           | <number> <digit>

<word> ::= <letter>
         | <word> <letter>
         | <word> '_'
         | <word> <digit>

<word_list> ::= <word>
             |  <word_list> <word>

<assignment_word> ::= <word> '=' <word>
```

Comment: Hmmm. Then `letter123=123` is not valid? ;) I assume number should be added somehow to `<word>`'s definition, shouldn't it?

Comment: @TrueY, it looks like you've caught a bug in the book I was referencing to.

Comment: -1 for an old, incorrect reference. That grammar mentions `bash` 2; `bash` 3, itself rare now, was released over 8 years ago.

Comment: @ivg: Just complete the definition of `<word>`. A `| <word> <digit>` seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @TrueY, I've updated the grammar definition. Just in case. Thanks, for pointing it!